# javascript / jquery - how to create a proper modal page overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I've been struggling for a couple weeks creating a modal dialog in javascript / jquery. On ios and android devices I get pretty consistent, working results - but in windows mobile / opera mobile / etc, the size of the modal never seems to be quite right - either i get excessive scrolling or the dialog is too short and so the background of the page beneath shows through at the bottom. I need to figure out the best way to size the modal (and resize on device orientation change).

This is what I'm doing currently:

CSS

```
#dialog { 
left: 0; top: 0; right:0; bottom: 0; 
position:absolute; z-index:4; color: #424242; font-size:14px; display:none; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#35848b, #6dbcc9); background: -ms-linear-gradient(#35848b, #6dbcc9); background: -o-linear-gradient(#35848b, #6dbcc9); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#35848b, #6dbcc9); 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (CALLED ON DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGE AND INITIAL PAGE LOAD)

```
viewportW = window.innerWidth;
viewportH = window.innerHeight;
$j('#dialog').css({'min-height' : viewportH+'px' });
```

I need to make sure that the dialog is always at least as high as the viewport, but also tall enough to cover any content below it. If anyone has any best practices on this or tutorials I can check out or anything, that'd be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the jQuery UI dialog?

Comment: Have you tried $(window).height() ?

Comment: @mheavers, Did you ever find a fix for this without having to use jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Here's a link to download the jQuery UI library:
http://jqueryui.com/download

Here's an article that explains how to make the dialog modal:
http://geekswithblogs.net/liammclennan/archive/2009/11/01/135934.aspx

```
<div class="make_me_a_dialog">Content of div</div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.make_me_a_dialog').dialog({ bgiframe: true,
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.5
            }                
        });
    });        
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Have you tried using `window.availHeight` instead of `window.innerHeight`?

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at JQuery UI - this example though is a dialog of a fixed height, and for me that is a dynamic value - it will need to change depending on the mobile device viewing the site, so that's the main issue I'm struggling with

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem changing the height to suit your purpose.

Comment: Well - the dialog has a lot of markup and logic tied to it - it's not something I want to create dynamically. I also don't want to include the jquery ui library if I don't have to

Comment: You don't have to use it. You were already using jQuery, so it seemed like it might be a good fit. Why do you think you'd have to create it dynamically?

Comment: Yeah - looks like I don't need to create it dynamically, but I'd much rather figure this out without having to incorporate jquery ui - it will involve me reconfiguring a lot of my code, and I still will have the height issue - which is the only problem I'm really trying to solve.

Comment: Edited my answer with something to try. Might work better for setting the height.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `outer` dimensions:

```
viewportH = window.outerHeight;
```