# How to make a whole page be a modal onload?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying for a while, to make an entire page to be a modal onload. And I have no result and no code to show. But I hope I will find some help here. 
 The thing is that I don't want to target anything from the other page (page2.html) , no id's, no classes.
 I don't want just *an element* from a page to be a modal, I want the **whole page** to be a modal.

So, for example ... I have this page :

> `page1.html`

```
<a href="page2.html">The link that takes me to the page 2</a>
```

Now I click that link and :

> `page2.html` pops-up like a modal

```
this is the page2.html's code -
that I do not want to have any id's or classes,
but I want it to be a modal!
```

So I want to know if there is a way to do that ... 
Something like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('page2.html').BeAmodal();
});
```

????...or some css tricks ... something ...anything!
 
Thank you ... a lot!

Comment: maybe this question has a valid solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744086/javascript-jquery-how-to-create-a-proper-modal-page-overlay

Comment: Why don't you just create a basic modal (with bootstrap or other) and load your HTML inside with `$("#myModal").load("page2.html")`? I don't see what's so hard to achieve, should be pretty easy